Mertens like estimates for sums over primes
Mertens estimates typically give
$$
\sum_{p<x} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log(x) + O(1).
$$
Can we use this do directly deduce an estimate for
$$
\sum_{p<x} \frac{1}{p^{1- \alpha}}?
$$
Here, $\alpha >0$.

Are you familiar with summation by parts, Abel summation, or integration by parts for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals? These are how you would typically try. But in this case, it's actually better to mimic a proof of Mertens estimates directly. If you used a stronger form of Mertens estimate, like $\sum 1/p = \log \log x + c + O(1/\log^2 x)$, then Abel summation/integration by parts/partial summation are enough to give the correct asymptotic.

I think here one needs to use some version of PNT to get the right asymptotic - note that even Mertens estimates need PNT (are equivalent to actually) in their sharpest forms, though they are more elementary in the basic form
